# Resolve options inside query_builder of custom form type

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a custom form type inherited from EntityType and it has a required option that will be used inside query_builder. How can I get the resolved value?

```
class MealPlanType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'class' => MealPlanHotel::class,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($resolver) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('meals')
                   **// Need to get hotel passed in form builder here**
                   // ->where('meals.hotel = :hotel')->setParameter('hotel', $hotel)
                    ->orderBy('meals.sortIndex', 'ASC');
            },

        ]);

        $resolver->setRequired(['hotel']);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial I found a solution to this problem:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'class' => MealPlanHotel::class,
        'query_builder' => function (Options $options) {
            return function(EntityRepository $er) use($options) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('meals')
                    ->where('meals.hotel = :hotel')->setParameter('hotel', $options['hotel'])
                    ->andWhere('meals.isEnabled = true')
                    ->orderBy('meals.sortIndex', 'ASC');
            };
        },

    ]);

    $resolver->setRequired(['hotel']);
}
```

You need to send a function with Options parameter to query_builder and the options will be populated inside the function.